# Почему не работает логическое "или" и in_array

Tags: javascript, php

помогите верстальщику, для себя решил поучить php, но что-то пошло не так
вообщем задача то простая нужно посчитать какой элемент в массиве arr = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,4,5,5,6,6,5,5,6,7,7,5,7,7,8,8,9,9] встречается чаще всего
на моем любом js я бы сделал что-то типа такого

```
function myFunc(arr){
  const objRepeatedChars = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {})

return objRepeatedChars
}
```

пытаюсь сделать на php

```
<?php
$arr = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,4,5,5,6,6,5,5,6,7,7,5,7,7,8,8,9,9];
$newArr = [];

foreach($arr as $value) {
   $newArr[$value] = ($newArr[$value] || 0) + 1;
}

print_r($newArr)

?>
```

ОШИБКА!!! Undefined array key
ну ок подумал я undefinded - это же false почему не сработало логическое или

ладно поискав нашел такую замечательную ф-ию как
in_array — Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве значение
вот оно подумал я. На каждой итерации цикла буду проверять  присутствует ли в массиве значение и если присутствует увеличивать

```
<?php
foreach($arr as $value) {
    if(in_array($newArr[$value], $arr)) $newArr[$value]++;
    else $newArr[$value] = 1;
}

?>
```

ОШИБКА!!! Undefined array key
вот это мне вообще не понравилось ну что не так то!

поискав ещё чуть обнаружил ещё замечательную ф-ию isset
ну думаю если и она не сработает на этом моё php заканчивается и вуаля!!!

```
<?php
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
     if(isset($newArr[$value])){
         $newArr[$value]++;
    } else {
         $newArr[$value] = 1;
     }
  }
 ?>
```

Ура!!
а вот так работает

Собственно вопрос какого...  почему первые 2 варианта не сработали?

Comment: `$newArr[$value] ?? 0` или в варианте 2 `in_array($value, $newArr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом варианте вместо

```
$newArr[$value] = ($newArr[$value] || 0) + 1;
```

напишите

```
$newArr[$value] = ($newArr[$value] ?? 0) + 1;
```

и всё.

---

ну или вам привычным способом:

```
$arr = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,2,4,5,5,6,6,5,5,6,7,7,5,7,7,8,8,9,9];

$newArr = array_reduce($arr, function($acc, $value) {
    $acc[$value] = ($acc[$value] ?? 0) + 1;
    return $acc;
}, []);

print_r($newArr);
```

---

Не сработал потому, что он говорит `Undefined offset: -5` а не `Undefined array key`. Это разные вещи. То есть в *PHP* если нет ключа он генерирует предупреждение, а не возвращает `undefined`. И проверить на существование можно через `isset`, который определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением, отличным от null. `isset` вернёт `false` при проверке переменной которая была установлена значением `null`. Также учтите, что `NULL`-символ ("\0") не равен константе `null`

`in_array` не сработал потому, что до него дело и не дошло вовсе. Потому что ошибка появилась раньше, как в описании выше

Comment: премного благодарен за развернутый ответ